# Swift 3 Core Data - init(context:) is only available on iOS 10 or newer

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

My code is as follows:

```
    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    let feed = Sources(context: managedObjectContext)
```

I am receiving the error "init(context:) is only available in iOS 10. What is the way I can do this in the pre-iOS 10 method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use following method to compatible with all versions:

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "YourEntityName", in: managedObjectContext)!
let feed = Source(entity: entity, insertInto: managedObjectContext)
```

It is tested under Swift 3.1.